# google maps geocoding not marking all places on the map

Tags: geocoding

below is the code ,there is an array which contains names of 62 places,but while geocoding not all 62 places are getting marked on the map,only very few places are getting marked on map.

function createMarker(latlng){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
  });

```js
var markers = ["chennai", "Kashmir", "Russia", "Jalandhar", "Netherlands", "Koregaon Park", "Piparia", "South Africa", "USA", "Siliguri", "Dhule", "United Kingdom", "Shendra", "Baramulla", "Haridwar", "New Delhi", "United Arab Emirates", "Ladakh", "Noida", "Shanghai", "Gurgaon", "Rajouri", "Netherlands", "Ranchi", "Abruzzo", "Waluj", "Ho Chi Minh", "Germany", "Bhopal", "Soenderborg", "Delhi", "Dindori", "Brazil", "Magarpatta", "Chennai", "Taiwan", "Jharsuguda", "Rakholi", "Turkey", "Denmark", "Bangalore", "Selangor", "Rajgarh", "Vardhaman Industrial Estate", "Sagar", "Jammu", "Beijing", "Jamshedpur", "Jabalpur", "SIDCUL", "Hyderabad", "PTB Rakholi", "Haimen", "Ahmedabad", "OFC Rakholi", "Mumbai", "Bafliaz", "Srinagar", "Argentina", "Dadra", "Mexico", "Tiruchirappalli"]
var map;
function initializeMaps(eventObject)
{
    

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap1'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000,78.0000),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      geocodeAddress(markers[i]);
    }
   
}
function geocodeAddress(location) {
var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location}, function(results, status) {
 // alert(status);
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

     // alert(results[0].geometry.location);
     // map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      createMarker(results[0].geometry.location,location);
    
    }
    else
    {
      alert("some problem in geocode" + status);
    }
  }); 
}








function createMarker(latlng){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i found a work around to mark all the places.at a time google geocodes only 11 requests,so i added a delay between every iteration and since there was delay between each hit to the geocoding server,geocoding was possible for all the places in the array.

```
for(i = 1; i < markers.length; i++){
(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        geocodeAddress(markers[i]);
    }, 1000 * i);
}(i));
```

}